# Slicing Multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am trying to remove specific indexes in a 2d array as follows.

```
a = [[1, *2, 3]
     [4, 5, 6*]
     [7*, 8, 9]]
```

I want to delete the specific indexes(with *) of a 3x3 array and make it 2x3 array.

like

```
a = [[1, 3]
     [4, 5]
     [8, 9]]
```

How to do that?

Update:

Error with delete():

[image]

Comment: That's not a multidimensional array. That's an array of arrays.

Comment: Is'nt it a 2D array?

Comment: Technically no because this is Pyhton not C/C++. It's a `list`. So you could call it a list of lists or a multidimensional list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pop()`

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> a[0].pop(1)
>>> a[1].pop(2)
>>> a[2].pop(0)
>>> a
[[1, 3], [4, 5], [8, 9]]
```

Using `del`

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> del a[0][1]
>>> del a[1][2]
>>> del a[2][0]
>>> a
[[1, 3], [4, 5], [8, 9]]
```

Using `numpy.delete()`

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
>>> b = numpy.zeros((3, 2))
>>> b[0] = numpy.delete(a[0], 1)
>>> b[1] = numpy.delete(a[1], 2)
>>> b[2] = numpy.delete(a[2], 0)
>>> b
array([[1, 3], [4, 5], [8, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks! What if its a numpy array that do not support pop?

Comment: You can use ```numpy.delete()```

Comment: Can you please show how to use numpy.delete() with this example?

Comment: its giving me an error. `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (3)`. Updated question.

Comment: Yes, because numpy 2d arrays must have consistent dimensions. 3,3 or 2,3 in your example. You'd have to create a new array as you change each row.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate it.  It would be helpful. By creating new array.

Comment: Updated the last example.

Answer (score 0):

If we use list of lists

```
...
delenda = [1,2,0]
for i, row in enumerate(a):
    row.pop(delenda[i])
```

also as a function

```
def multipop(list_of_lists_2D, delenda):
    for i, row in enumerate(list_of_lists_2D):
        row.pop(delenda[i])

multipop(a,[1,2,0])
```

note that `pop` operates in place, no need to return the modified list